# Cannot Read Property of Null / API Call in ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to map over an array of objects (which comes from an API call which I have then set as the State in a React Component, this is all done within the `ComponentDidMount()`), and then use the output of the map to pass as `props` to another component which will then set markers on my Google Map.

I'm assuming that the map function is executing before the API call has had time to complete but I'm not 100% sure how to work around it.

```
    async componentDidMount(){
    let appKey = '';
    let id = '';
    const url = `https://api.tfl.gov.uk/BikePoint/app_key=${appKey}&app_id=${id}`;
    await axios.get(url)
        .then((response) => {
            const data = response.data;
            let bikePointsInfo = data.map((d) => {
                return {
                name: d.commonName,
                lat: d.lat,
                lon: d.lon,
                bikes: Number((Object.entries(d.additionalProperties[6])[4])[1]),
                spaces: Number((Object.entries(d.additionalProperties[7])[4])[1])
                };
            });
            this.setState({bikePointsInfo});
        })
    }

    render () {
    const markers = this.state.bikePointsInfo.map(marker => (
        <MapPoint
            name = {this.state.bikePointsInfo.name}
            bikes = {marker.bikes}
            spaces = {marker.spaces}
            lon = {marker.lon}
            lng = {marker.lng}
        />
    ))
    return (
        <div>
            <Map
                google={this.props.google}
                zoom={14}
                initialCenter={{lat: 51.5080, lng: -0.1281}}
            >
            {markers}
            </Map>
        </div>
    );
}
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'bikePointsInfo' of null

Comment: the error means that `this.state` is `null`. Did you forget to set an initial state in your component's constructor?

Comment: I did set initially as an empty array, but was getting a different TypeError: Cannot read property Map of undefined.

Comment: In Axios, aren't responses already parsed as a JavaScript object without the need to use .json()

Comment: sorry, it seems you're right, I'll delete the comment (I've never used axios myself). In that case the problem must be that the data you get back has no `data` property. Try printing the entire response to see what you have.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this :

```
async componentDidMount() {
  let appKey = '';
  let id = '';
  const url = `https://api.tfl.gov.uk/BikePoint/app_key=${appKey}&app_id=${id}`;
  await axios.get(url)
    .then((response) => {
      const data = response.data;
      let bikePointsInfo = data.map((d) => {
        return {
          name: d.commonName,
          lat: d.lat,
          lon: d.lon,
          bikes: Number((Object.entries(d.additionalProperties[6])[4])[1]),
          spaces: Number((Object.entries(d.additionalProperties[7])[4])[1])
        };
      });
      this.setState({
        bikePointsInfo
      });
    })
}
updated() {
  this.renderComponent()
}

renderComponent() {
  if (this.state.bikePointsInfo) {
    const markers = this.state.bikePointsInfo.map(marker => ( <
      MapPoint name = {
        this.state.bikePointsInfo.name
      }
      bikes = {
        marker.bikes
      }
      spaces = {
        marker.spaces
      }
      lon = {
        marker.lon
      }
      lng = {
        marker.lng
      }
      />
    ))
    return ( 
        <div >

      <Map google = {
        this.props.google
      }
      zoom = {
        14
      }
      initialCenter = {
        {
          lat: 51.5080,
          lng: -0.1281
        }
      } 
      >
      {
        markers
      } 
      </Map> 
      </div>
    );
  }

  return ( 
    <div >
    <Map google = {
      this.props.google
    }
    zoom = {
      14
    }
    initialCenter = {
      {
        lat: 51.5080,
        lng: -0.1281
      }
    } >
    </Map> 
    </div>
  );
}
render() {
  return this.renderComponent()
}
```

---

}